# Check m3u8 web url with C#

Tags: c#, m3u8

I'm doing a little function inside a program, and I'll like to check if a m3u8 link is working. However, I'm not able to do it correctly, because some links are not working, but they are returning a status code equals to OK. Here you have my code:

```
var textBox     = (TextBox)this.FindName("urlToCheck");
var request     = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox.Text.Trim());
request.Method  = "HEAD";

try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var success  = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;

    if (success) MessageBox.Show("Apparently the link is working");
    else MessageBox.Show("Apparently the link is not working");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Tthe link is not working");
}
```

How can I detect if there is real stream inside the working links? I'm not sure how to do it, how to detect a working URL Stream and one that not. The only way now for me, is by using the VLC Player.

Lot of thanks for your help.

Best regards

Comment: Define "not working". A request that returns 200 works by definition - it returned whatever you asked in the body. If you want to verify that the body is what you expected, you should check the body contents, not the status code.

Comment: UHmm, for example, here we have the Space Station Stream of the ISS: http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/9408562/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8

This one is working, however this one:

http://iptvservice.ddns.net:8000/live/yannis/yannis/2322.m3u8

Is not. I don't know exactly how to detect the difference, for me, the way to detect it is by using the VLC player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it by checking the status code of the link and the contentlength:

`var success = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.ContentLength > 0;`